# Uncaught Reference Error: callback not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I want to get the IP address of the machine with javascript ajax.

I used the site https://geoip-db.com/jsonp/. with ajax but the error keeps getting up.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'https://geoip-db.com/jsonp/',
    dataType: 'jsonp'
});
```

The error message is:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: callback is not defined
>       at ?callback=jQuery19009023082782456009_1560194259394&_=1560194259395:1

Comment: You haven’t specified the callback. See https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/working-with-jsonp/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `jQuery.ajax({ url: 'https://geoip-db.com/jsonp/', dataType: 'jsonp' });`

Use `jQuery.ajax({ url: 'https://geoip-db.com/json/', dataType: 'json' });`